# How to make a single table with data in Python from 2 csv files with a common id?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, csv

There are 2 files client.csv (15gb 160 million rows) and phone.csv.

An example of a client.csv file:

| id | name | email | contract_number | address_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Pupkin Vasya | Pupkin_Vasya@mail.ru | 43784578 | 5283512 |

An example of a phone.csv file:

| id | phone |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 79999999999 |

We should end up with:

| id | phone | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 79999999999 | Pupkin Vasya | Pupkin_Vasya@mail.ru |

I just need to write the data I need either in csv or in a SQLite table.

Theoretically, I need to read the one with numbers and use its id to browse data from another file, but how to do it is not clear.

I tried this code:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[123], 'name': ['Pupkin Vasya'], 'email': ['Pupkin_Vasya@mail.ru'], 'usless_info': [1]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[123], 'phone': [79999999999], 'usless_info': [1]})
df = pd.merge(left=df_2[['id', 'phone']], right=df_1[['id', 'name', 'email']], how='left', on='id')
df.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```

but the files are larger than my RAM capacity

I need to find a solution without using the pandas library

UPD:
If id from file client.csv has no data in file phone.csv then data from file client.csv goes to the final file, but column 'phone' remains empty

Comment: Are rows of the files sorted?

Comment: @Scott Hunter files are sorted by id, but in the file client.csv there are id's that do not have a number in the file phone.csv

Comment: What do you want to do records that don't have a corresponding one in the other file?

Comment: Write to the final file with an empty 'phone' column

Comment: Since the files are sorted on id, I would begin iterating both files if the ids of the current rows match then you do your thing, if they do not match then get the next row from the file that has the lower current id. Repeat. If you want an example let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in pseudo-Python:

```
c = read_next_client()
p = read_next_phone()
while c != None and p != None:
    if c.id == p.id:
        write_combined_record(c,p)
        c = read_next_client()
        p = read_next_phone()
    elif c.id < p.id:
        write_combined_record(c,None)
        c = read_next_client()
    else:
        p = read_next_phone()
while c != None:
    write_combined_record(c,None)
    c = read_next_client()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that ought to be pretty close to a solution (I unfortunately don't have your actual files to test with).  The basic idea is to iterate through the two input files together, keeping them in sync according to the `id` field, and writing the output file as you go.

```
import csv

with (
    open('client.csv', newline='', encoding='utf8-sig') as client_file,
    open('phone.csv', newline='', encoding='utf8-sig') as phone_file,
    open('final.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as final_file,
):
    client_csv = csv.reader(client_file)
    phone_csv = csv.reader(phone_file)
    final_csv = csv.writer(final_file)
    # CSV headers.
    assert next(client_csv) == (
        'id', 'name', 'email', 'contract_number', 'address_id'
    ), 'Bad headers in client.csv'
    assert next(phone_csv) == ('id', 'phone'), 'Bad headers in phone.csv'
    final_csv.writerow(('id', 'phone', 'name', 'email'))
    try:
        # Initialize lookaheads for the two files.
        c_id = ''
        c_id, name, email, _, _ = next(client_csv)
        p_id, phone = next(phone_csv)
        while True:
            if p_id == c_id:
                # Matching row -- merge and advance both files.
                final_csv.writerow((c_id, phone, name, email))
                c_id = ''
                c_id, name, email, _, _ = next(client_csv)
                p_id, phone = next(phone_csv)
            elif int(p_id) > int(c_id):
                # Phone is ahead of client.
                final_csv.writerow((c_id, '', name, email))
                c_id = ''
                c_id, name, email, _, _ = next(client_csv)
            else:
                # Client is ahead of phone.
                p_id, phone = next(phone_csv)
    except StopIteration:
        # We hit the end of one of the files.
        if c_id:
            final_csv.writerow((c_id, '', name, email))
    # Exhaust any remaining entries in client.
    for c_id, name, email, _, _ in client_csv:
        final_csv.writerow((c_id, '', name, email))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv.DictReader`. You can open the 3 files - `client.csv`, `phone.csv` and `final.csv`.

You then need to read `client.csv` and store it in a dictionary.

Then you can iterate over the `phone.csv` and check if the key found in the dictionary. if its found then you can update that dictionary with the required value.

Here's the code -

```
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(10**5)

with open('client.csv', 'r') as client_file, open('phone.csv', 'r') as phone_file, open('final.csv', 'w', newline='') as final_file:
    client_reader = csv.DictReader(client_file)
    phone_reader = csv.DictReader(phone_file)

    merged_data = {}

    for row in client_reader:
        client_id = row['id']
        merged_data[row_id] = {'id': client_id, 'name': row['name'], 'email': row['email']}

    for row in phone_reader:
        phone_id = row['id']
        if phone_id in merged_data:
            merged_data[phone_id]['phone'] = row['phone']

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(final_file, fieldnames=['id', 'phone', 'name', 'email'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for row in merged_data.values():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You're loading both files into memory, which is the thing that OP is trying to avoid by not using Pandas.

Comment: In that case, we can define a chunk size. I believe it will work in pandas too. its like opening the file and the reading it desired chunks in a for loop.and keep on appending the results

Comment: What if the number of entries missing from `phone.csv` exceeds the chunk size?

Comment: I think I can use `csv.field_size_limit(10**9)`

Comment: @Caxa, I believe that should work. Please give it a try.

Comment: @Pravash Panigrahi Tried your code both raw and with my changes. Couldn't do anything.